# Runtime error with python code online, works offline

Tags: python, runtime-error

The code runs successfully offline, however, when uploaded to a code challenge site it gives me a `RuntimeError`. I am unsure why it is doing this.

My code:

```
inputinteger = int(input(""))
N = inputinteger

inputinteger2 = int(input(""))
M = inputinteger2

A = int(N / M)

if (N % M == 0):
    B = 0
    print("masing-masing " + str(A))
    print("bersisa " + str(B))

else:
    B = int(N % M);
    print("masing-masing " + str(A))
    print("bersisa " + str(B))
```

*Note: "masing-masing" in English means "each". "bersisa" in English means "remainder".*

Inputting some test input `15` and `3` gives the expected result. The code however does not work when run online.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you provide us the full error message?

Comment: You seem to mix `print` and `print()`. Python2 vs Python3 issue?

Comment: I think the bottom one is just the instructions for the challenge. I see nothing wrong with the top piece of code, and tested it myself, and it works perfectly fine. If there is a problem with the online compiler I would guess it's the python version

Comment: Which site is it? I have experienced this before, and it was often to do with the way the script interacted with the testing server.

Comment: In Python 2, `input` has a different behavior: the input value is evaluated as Python code. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

Comment: @ggrelet it was just works fine but a code challenge site it gives me a runtime error.

Comment: @Julien oh..let me see what differences of them are

Comment: @Recessive yeah...i think so.let me check what version of python i used. a code challenge site it asks pyhton3.

Comment: @gmds [link](https://training.ia-toki.org/training/curriculums/1/courses/1/chapters/3/problems/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% positive on this, but it is a best guess and there's not enough room in the comments.

For python 2, it may be that you are meant to use `raw_input` instead of `input` in your code. That being said upon testing python 2 code, it seems a lot of online interpreters don't work with `input`, or `raw_input` anyway. See here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php
 and here: https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=python. If you put in this code:

```
a = raw_input()
```

It will fail with an EOF error. I believe this is because these interpreters don't actually allow for input.

if you change the lines `inputinteger = int(input(""))` and `inputinteger2 = int(input(""))` to just `inputinteger = 4` and `inputinteger2 = 5`, I think you'll find that you no longer get a run time error.

Since you said English is your second language, if that was hard to understand, here it is in a bit simpler terms:

Some old python versions do not use `input`. They use `raw_input`. Try replacing `input` with `raw_input`.

If that does not work, maybe the online python does not let you use `input` or `raw_input`. Try using code with no `input`.

EDIT:

based on how the website makes it seem you will be receiving your input, I would try changing your code to the following:

```
inputinteger, inputinteger2 = raw_input("").split(" ")
N=int(inputinteger)
M=int(inputinteger2)

A=int(N/M);

if(N%M==0):
    B=0
    print("masing-masing "+str(A))
    print("bersisa "+str(B))

else:
    B=int(N%M);
    print("masing-masing "+str(A))
    print("bersisa "+str(B))
```

If that doesn't work, I'm sorry but I'm completely out of ideas as to why it might be failing. I've tested with the example input they gave on the website and it works perfectly. We know you have the right answer, if it means anything..

Edit: Further explanation:

So the website said you would be receiving input in the following format (as an example):

```
15 3
```

This means, you only received a single string. The line:

```
inputinteger, inputinteger2 = raw_input("").split(" ")
```

Is taking in that single string, and using `.split(" ")` to split it into different values (stored in a list) on either side of the empty space. So essentially, it assigns

```
inputinteger, inputinteger2 = ["15", "3"]
```

Which gives you the appropriate values for those variables. From there, your old code works perfectly.

Comment: yeah...with following ur instructions, i got no longer a run time error. about     raw_input , i can't use it because i think im using pyhton3. And, i have been try with initialization integers on each its variables as u said try using code with no     input  but got wrong answer

Comment: @giffaro97 see my edit, hopefully that will get it to work.

Comment: Thanks..it gets accepted!! can you explain me what the one problem is ?

Comment: oops...i didnt pay attention

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer above.

The online challenge site is not or may not be supplying the input required for the code to run. I will suggest you simply replace either `input()` or `raw_input()` with actual values that the system can work with.